# Is there a way to store the running result of rmarkdown chunks into different env?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Suppose I have 1 or several chunks in rmarkdown

````
```{r chunk1}
v = 1
```
````

And second

````
```{r chunk2}
result = v + 1
```
````

Is there a way to run these two chunks and store each time's result into different env? So I just change env and v to different values,and go through the chunks to get final result.
So that I don't need to overwrite my result or change my code everytime.

This is part of an rmarkdown file and I want to compare some result before I move on.
Seems I can wrap each chunk with

```
env1 = new.env()
local({},envir = env1)
```

but it seems a little ugly,I hope something like:

````
```{r, envir = env1}
```
````

and I could run the chunks and then setenv(env = env2)...etc. Then I could compare env1$result,env2$result,env3$result... with no worries to corrupt my current env or overwrite existing variables.

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what you want to achieve. In your example, `chunk2` uses `v` which was (presumably) defined in `chunk1`. So if you ran those in different environments, your `chunk2` would fail because no name `v` would be defined in the current environment.

Comment: I mean if I could set each chunk's env into the same one? like ```{r chunk1,env = env1}; ``` ```{r chunk2,env = env1}```; and run; everything went into env1, after I finish; I change each of the chunk's env to env2, and run again, and put everything into env2, is that clear? @Konrad Rudolph ;currently everything goes into global env if I run one by one and if I use render in knitr then it go through entir rmarkdown, which is not I needed too.

Comment: Could you define a new chunk before each of these, that reads data from a file or however you get your data, and then you change only that one chunk that influences all later ones? I believe that's more manageable than relying on changing chunk **options**.

Comment: Hmm. This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): RMarkdown is *fundamentally unsuited* to the concept of rerunning the document in the same session. On the contrary: the entire point is to have reproducible documents that, when rerun, will yield the same output. And documents should generally be run in one go, not chunk by chunk (except during the writing). — And once you do that, the problem becomes trivial to solve, because `rmarkdown::render()` allows you to specify the environment that your code should run in.

Comment: (In other words: this isn’t a limitation of ‘knitr’/‘rmarkdown’, it’s a conscious design decision.)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph you mean to write everthing into one rmarkdown file and using render's env option to finish my job; seems a way, however, seems I only need part of my code to be rerun and there are several chunks above which setup the background to me so I can't do the rest without them.but they didn't change so I don't need to rerun it everytime.

Comment: @mkranj that way I need to store each result, so that could compare my result. While I simplified my problem, in real case I need to store more than just one result and compare each of them. so I have to store every round's results seperately, which is doable but not convinient.

Comment: maybe, instead of re-running sections of your code with different input to yield different results, try to put the reusable code inside function(s) and then you can call the function with different input each time, yielding different results.  Then you an run the document from top to bottom without repeating some chunks